# postsRequest pagesRequest missing variables

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a project, where they are using GULP. I didn't have any luck in getting it to work. I am trying to get my search.js file to work. and at this time  I am missing 2 variables in my file. Here is my full code https://pastebin.com/raw/USnh34g3

```
postsRequest = fetch(...),
pagesRequest = fetch(...),
```

I have tried several snippets of code and even a vanilla version of my search.js version, but the current code I am running seems to fit my current course best.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

is the error i get, I am thinking it has to do something with the fact that I haven't undeclared variables.

Comment: try posting your code so SO members are able to assist. However, that error is probably due to a random `)`.

Comment: "I am thinking it has to do something with the fact that I haven't undeclared variables" — It isn't. The error message is quite specific. You have a `)` somewhere that it wasn't expecting a `)`. It isn't obvious where that is. Provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**. Don't link to pastebin.

Comment: Hope the error is not because you left `fetch(...)` as it is... Is this exactly what you have in your code?: https://pastebin.com/raw/USnh34g3

Comment: Also, the prev line ends with a semicolon, and no `var`, `const` or `let` is on the next....

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> fetch(...)
> ```

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) consists of `...` **followed by** something that can be expanded into the arguments you are passing to the function.

You omitted that and went directly to `)`, which wasn't expected.

You probably just need to replace `...` with the URL you are trying to fetch from.